# SQL to count occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I want to build 4 extra columns (below right 4) to my table.

- Count the occurrences of "device+date"
- In separated columns which match with "source" value in the row

Here's the Excel formula for the last 2 columns, how can I write the logic in SQL?

```
S1_count_in_the_date:
=COUNTIFS(F:F,F2,A:A,"S1")
--countifs(device+date column, device+date value, source column, "S1")--

S2_count_in_the_date:
=COUNTIFS(F:F,F2,A:A,"S2")
--countifs(device+date column, device+date value, source column, "S2")--
```

My SQL attempt for S1_count_in_the_date:

```
COUNT(source+device+date) OVER (PARTITION BY device, date)
```

| source | device | date | ... | source+device+date | device+date | S1_count_in_the_date | S2_count_in_the_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | A | 2021-01-03 | … | S1A2021-01-03 | A2021-01-03 | 1 | 2 |
| S2 | A | 2021-01-03 | … | S2A2021-01-03 | A2021-01-03 | 1 | 2 |
| S2 | A | 2021-01-03 | … | S2A2021-01-03 | A2021-01-03 | 1 | 2 |

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your best attempt in SQL... and clarify your data, I can't why you have the values you have.

Comment: Is that `COUNTIFS` formula meant only for row 2, in other words: would row 3 be `=COUNTIFS(F:F,F3,A:A,"S1")`? And does this not work `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY device, date, source)`?

Answer (score 0):

The last two columns can be a column in a separate select using `group by`. Please see the snippet below and see if it helps.

Query:

```
select 
d.source, d.device, d.date, 
concat(d.source, d.device, cast(d.date as Date)) source_device_date, concat(d.device, cast(d.date as Date)) source_device_date, 
--sdd.sdd_count 
case when sdd.source='S1' then sdd.sdd_count end s1_count, 
case when sdd.source='S2' then sdd.sdd_count end s2_count 
from 
devices d 
join ( 
       select 
            source, device, date, count(*) sdd_count 
       from 
            devices 
       group by source, device, date 
     ) sdd on d.source = sdd.source 
            and d.device=sdd.device 
            and d.date=sdd.date
```

[Fiddle for reference](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69f5f5e2a5941cc1cf48e0f705d64beb)

Comment: Thanks a lot praveen, is it possible to breakdown "sdd_count" into two columns? I need to do calculation based on them.  Also, since my table contains more columns than it shows above, I can't group the count since it'll return only 1 if other columns are all added into the group statement

Comment: I did split the columns into two using case statements. Please see if that helps. 

Hope you dont need the count of S2 under S1_Count column. 

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23499d1d67bf4847680dcaee6e1531c9

Thanks

Comment: Done. Great. Thanks